# Generating Combinatorics of Large Numbers in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, combinatorics

**tl;dr**: How should I be dealing with numbers like `20! * 20!` in Objective-C?

---

I'm learning Objective-C by working through [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net). It's been quite fun, but one problem I've been running in to is working with arbitrarily large numbers. I'm still pretty green on these things, so I don't know why something like, say, Python, handles large numbers with ease compared to Obj-C.

Take for example `Problem 15`:

> `Starting in the top left corner of a 2 x 2 grid, there are 6 routes (without backtracking) to the bottom right corner.`
>
> `How many routes are there through a 20 x 20 grid?`

That's easy. Using combinatorics:

> (20+20)! / 20!(20!)
> -> 815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000 / 5919012181389927685417441689600000000
> -> 137846528820

In Python:

```py
import math  
print math.factorial(40) / (math.factorial(20) * math.factorial(20))
```

In Objective-C, though? I have't yet found a way to force such a large numbers through. Using the 2 x 2 example works fine. I can get `9C4 = 126`, as it should be. But how should I be dealing with numbers like `20!`?

I've dallied with trying to use `NSDecimalNumber`, which appears to support more numerals per number, assuming you can convert it to `Mantissa x Exponent` and don't mind loss of precision, but that didn't prove to be too useful, as I couldn't figure out how to have Obj-C create a Mantissa from a `%llu` and I *do* mind loss of precision.

The code I have so far properly generates the factorials, as it appears `unsigned long long` handles values so large, but chokes up on `x * y`, and thus `getCombinatoricOf:20 and:20` returns `1`.

```c
#import "Problem15.h"

@implementation Problem15

- (unsigned long long)factorial:(NSNumber *)number {
    unsigned long long temp = 1;
    for (int i = [number intValue]; i > 0; i--) {
        temp *= i;
    }
    return temp;
}

- (unsigned long long)getCombinatorcOf:(NSNumber *)x and:(NSNumber *)y {
    NSNumber *n = @([x intValue] + [y intValue]);
    NSNumber *n_factorial = @([self factorial:n]);
    NSNumber *x_factorial = @([self factorial:x]);
    NSNumber *y_factorial = @([self factorial:y]);
    return ([n_factorial unsignedLongLongValue] / ([x_factorial unsignedLongLongValue] * [y_factorial unsignedLongLongValue]));
}

- (NSString *)answer {
    NSNumber *x = @5;
    NSNumber *y = @4;
    unsigned long long answer = [self getCombinatoricOf:x and:y];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\nProblem 15: \nHow many routes are there through a 20 x 20 grid? \n%llu", answer];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Objective-C, but you could just use [GMP](http://gmplib.org) just as an ordinary C library.

There are also Objective-C wrappers fo GMP, like [GMPInt](https://github.com/bmorton/GMPInt).

Comment: This worked wonderfully with minimal setup; thanks! It **does** worry me that the Wrapper hasn't been updated in 2 years (had to manually edit for ARC support) and the calls are pretty weird (e.g. to multiply two `GMPInt`s together was: `[myGMPInt multiplyWithGMP:myOtherGMPInt];`. This in and of itself isn't wierd, but the fact that it returns a `void`, and I couldn't assign it to a new `GMPInt` kind of threw me off. The deeper question still stands (if you have any answer): Why doesn't Obj-C/C have support for arbitrarily large numbers like Python does? What's the difference?

Comment: I think the ObjC GMP wrapper project, isn't looking very updated. I mostly linked to it so you could look at how he does the wrapping and the GMP C calls.

Comment: I think the reason for Objective-C's lack of a large number class is because it's a small language—a small extension to standard ANSI C—with a different philosophy than Python, Java or C++. I think this is also carried on to the libraries. For example, look at how very few data structures Core Foundation includes—not much more than an array, a dictionary/hash and a set.